# putting img in div leads to them dissapearing

Tags: html, css, angular

For some reason when I tried to make a background and add images to it the images just dissapear.

```css
.Background1{
    position:relative;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    content:url("/assets/backgroundlayer1.jpg")
}
.Background2{
    position:absolute;
    top:35%;
    left:25%;
    height:75%;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Background1" name="Background1" id="Background">
 <img class="Background2" name="Background2" id="Background" src="/asset/Background2.png">
</div>
```

Edit: I want background2 to fit on background1.

Comment: FYI, the `name` attribute is intended for naming form attributes-- it is not a valid attribute to attach to a `<div/>` or `<img/>` element.

Comment: Instead of `content:url("/assets/backgroundlayer1.jpg")` you might try using `background-image: url("/assets/backgroundlayer1.jpg")`

Comment: Do yo want the first image to fill the given space? Will it have the same aspect ratio as the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things wrong .. You are calling the background image with `content` when you should be using the `background` property.

[CONTENT PROPORTY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

[BACKGROUND PROPERTY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

The second, you're trying to assign a height percentage where it is not allowed (the element is relative).. You need absolute definition (`px` or `pt` for example):

```
.Background1{
    position:relative;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
    background:url("/assets/backgroundlayer1.jpg") no-repeat;
```

Comment: I can see the image now, but I can't change the size.

Comment: You need to read more on CSS [BACKGROUND SIZE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) will get you started.  I recommend you take a tutorial and get the basics down.

Comment: No like I literally can't change ANY of the CSS settings, as the size will either remain the same or cause the image to dissapear.

Answer (score 1):

Use the background-image property instead of the content property. The content property is overiding the content of your div, thus removing the image.

```
.Background1{
    position:relative;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url('/assets/backgroundlayer1.jpg')
}
```

Comment: The image just completely dissapeared.